# Legitimate user or hacker -Terminal?

Tags: terminal, security, user-account, accounts

I have recently used the terminal and entered the command `sudo -s` and then `dscl . -list /users`  so I could see all accounts/users who have access to my mac.

How do I know which names are supposed to be there and which aren't? Luckily I read on another post that *nobody* and *daemon* appeared in their list so that calms me down slightly, but does anyone have a link to a list of which accounts are suppose to be there?

Right now, there are over 25 names, a lot look like file locations but I am freaked out!

Comment: The number of entries doesn't surprise me. If you want somebody to look over the list and give feedback, please put the whole list into the question.

Answer (score 4):

All users account starting with an `_` are automatically generated by the system. For example, `_lp` is an account used to manage the Printing Services without the use of the priviledged account `root`.
This is a separation of priviledges and a good protection.

For all other account names,
`daemon` and `nobody` are also generated by the system.

For the remaining accounts, let's say you see a suspect user account `bond`, use the following command:

```
finger bond
```

to check what `bond` account is used for and when it was last used to connect on your system.