# dscl . -list /Users Unusually Long All Legitimate Or Hacked?

Tags: terminal, command-line, security, user-account

Can someone look over my **file system list?**
(Getting very late here + can't find **decent answer...**)

I'm a bit worried the list is **quite long...** THANK YOU!

I've **disabled** my filesharing on a **clean install** but it could be that my computer is **hacked** and is now a **hackintosh** with remote login...

If this is true I would like **advice** on how to get rid off that...

[Legitimate user or hacker -Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94438/legitimate-user-or-hacker-terminal)

```
root@mac-mini-of-myself ~ # dscl . -list /Users 

_amavisd
_analyticsd
_appinstalld
_appleevents
_applepay
_appowner
_appserver
_appstore
_ard
_assetcache
_astris
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_captiveagent
_ces
_clamav
_cmiodalassistants
_coreaudiod
_coremediaiod
_coreml
_ctkd
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_datadetectors
_demod
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_diskimagesiod
_displaypolicyd
_distnote
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_driverkit
_eppc
_findmydevice
_fpsd
_ftp
_fud
_gamecontrollerd
_geod
_hidd
_iconservices
_installassistant
_installcoordinationd
_installer
_jabber
_kadmin_admin
_kadmin_changepw
_knowledgegraphd
_krb_anonymous
_krb_changepw
_krb_kadmin
_krb_kerberos
_krb_krbtgt
_krbfast
_krbtgt
_launchservicesd
_lda
_locationd
_logd
_lp
_mailman
_mbsetupuser
_mcxalr
_mdnsresponder
_mobileasset
_mysql
_nearbyd
_netbios
_netstatistics
_networkd
_nsurlsessiond
_oahd
_ondemand
_postfix
_postgres
_qtss
_reportmemoryexception
_rmd
_sandbox
_screensaver
_scsd
_securityagent
_softwareupdate
_spotlight
_sshd
_svn
_taskgated
_teamsserver
_timed
_timezone
_tokend
_trustd
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
_wwwproxy
_xserverdocs
myself
daemon
nobody
root
```

Comment: What's wrong with this list?

Comment: Except for "myself", those match what I have on a pretty clean macOS 11.5.1 system. All those accounts actually improve security, as they're used to isolate off various system components so a security vulnerability in one is harder to use to attack other parts of the OS.

Comment: myself is my own account